# Why is my collision response not stopping my player from going through walls (SDL2, C++)?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, collision, sdl-2, tile

While I found many problems that are similar too mine, none of the solutions solved my problem.

I've been experimenting with SDL2 in C++ (Visual C++) and the entity-component-system (ECS). But I just can't figure out the bug in my collision response.

So here it is: My player sometimes gets set back to its origin when it encounters something like a rock (a simple gray tile). But sometimes it goes right through and gets stuck or ends up on the other side.

[image: Collision is detected sometimes, but not always.]

I can only assume it has something to do with the data changed in between frames, so it isn't always caught. But for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Here is my rectangular detection method:

```
bool Collision::RectIntersect(const SDL_Rect& a, const SDL_Rect& b, SDL_Rect& intersect)
{
    intersect = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    int leftX = std::max(a.x, b.x);
    int rightX = std::min(a.x + a.w, b.x + b.w);
    int topY = std::max(a.y, b.y);
    int bottomY = std::min(a.y + a.h, b.y + b.h);

    if (leftX < rightX && topY < bottomY)
    {
        intersect = { leftX, topY, rightX - leftX, bottomY - topY };
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is my snippet where my inputs are handled and subsequently any collision detections are resolved before the code actually moves anything:

```
void InputComponent::handleEvents(SDL_Event* e)
{
    const Uint8 *keyboardState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    if (e != nullptr)
    {
        /*
            keyHeld: array of 4 for each direction (+/- x, +/- y (WASD))
            hold value true, if pressed down, otherwise false
        */
        if (keyboardState[SDL_SCANCODE_A])
        {
            keyHeld[0] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            keyHeld[0] = false;
        }

        if (keyboardState[SDL_SCANCODE_D])
        {
            keyHeld[1] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            keyHeld[1] = false;
        }

        if (keyboardState[SDL_SCANCODE_W])
        {
            keyHeld[2] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            keyHeld[2] = false;
        }

        if (keyboardState[SDL_SCANCODE_S])
        {
            keyHeld[3] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            keyHeld[3] = false;
        }
    }

    /*
        tmpVel: Vector to store the assumed velocity in x- and y-direction
    */
    Vector2D tmpVel(0.0f, 0.0f);
    // left and right (A and D)
    if (keyHeld[0] && !keyHeld[1])  // left
    {
        tmpVel.x = -1.0f;
    }
    else if (!keyHeld[0] && keyHeld[1])  // right
    {
        tmpVel.x = 1.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        tmpVel.x = 0.0f; // left and right cancel each other out
    }

    // up and down (W and S)
    if (keyHeld[2] && !keyHeld[3]) // up
    {
        tmpVel.y = -1.0f;
    }
    else if (!keyHeld[2] && keyHeld[3]) // down
    {
        tmpVel.y = 1.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        tmpVel.y = 0.0f; // up and down cancel each other out
    }

    /*
        check for collision with presumed direction according to tmpVel
    */
    SDL_Rect intersection;

    // get current player position
    SDL_Rect movedPlayer = entity->getComponent<CollisionComponent>().getCollider();

    // add trajectory of theoretical movement
    movedPlayer.x += static_cast<int>(tmpVel.x * vel_->getSpeed());
    movedPlayer.y += static_cast<int>(tmpVel.y * vel_->getSpeed());

    bool hasCollided = false;

    // collect all collidable objects
    for (auto& c : manager_->getGroup(GroupLabel::GR_COLLIDERS))
    {

        // check player against each collidable tile
        //if (SDL_IntersectRect(&movedPlayer, &c->getComponent<CollisionComponent>().getCollider(), &intersection))
        if (Collision::RectIntersect(movedPlayer, c->getComponent<CollisionComponent>().getCollider(), intersection))
        {
            // collision on x-axis
            if (intersection.w > 0)
            {
                // set velocity on x-axis to 0
                vel_->setVelocityX(0.0f);
                // reset player position back according to width of intersected rectangle
                pos_->setPosX(pos_->getPos().x + (static_cast<float>(intersection.w) * (-tmpVel.x)));
            }

            // collision on y-axis
            if (intersection.h > 0)
            {
                // set velocity on y-axis to 0
                vel_->setVelocityY(0.0f);
                // reset player position back according to height of intersected rectangle
                pos_->setPosY(pos_->getPos().y + (static_cast<float>(intersection.h) * (-tmpVel.y)));
            }

            hasCollided = true;
        }
    }

    if (!hasCollided)
    {
        vel_->setVelocity(tmpVel);
    }
}
```

Can anybody put me in the right direction?

Comment: This collision detection code would be a nice target for some unit test.

Comment: My VS 2017 doesn't seem to like unit tests. So I've I only checked it out on paper. It seems to be solid. I've got the source from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7356/how-to-find-rectangle-intersection-on-a-coordinate-plane

Answer (score 0):

What happens when the right edge of the player exactly equals the left edge of the rock? It looks like the collision is not detected, since the test is for `(leftX < rightX)`. So the velocity is updated and the player is moved by the velocity. (It's odd that you simply update the velocity and later move the player instead of just moving them to the new already calculated position.) If you change the check to `(leftX <= rightX)`, does the problem persist?

Comment: The problem persists. I've got the code from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7356/how-to-find-rectangle-intersection-on-a-coordinate-plane

No Unit-Tests, but pen and paper sufficed. I used this to get the intersection of the rectangles in the same go. Thought was the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there are two things wrong with your collision detection. The first is that you're testing `(leftX < rightX && topY < bottomY)` when you should be testing `(leftX <= rightX && topY <= bottomY)`. If you fix this your code will work in *most* situations.

The second problem you've got, which may not become apparent straight away, is that your are performing collision detection for discreet points in time. If your player has a large enough velocity vector you may end up with this situation:

- Update 1: Player is in front of wall travelling towards it. AABB test shows no collision.
- Update 2: Player is behind wall travelling away from it. AABB test shows no collision.

Your AABB test is correct and yet the player has passed through the wall. The naive approach to fixing this is to test more often (update 1.5 may have shown a collision), or to limit player velocity. Both approaches will require a lot of fine tuning especially if you're dealing with objects that can move at different speeds and walls with differing thickness.

A more robust approach is to take account of velocity in your test. Since you know the velocity of your AABB you can project this shape along its velocity vector. If you do this for both AABBs you'll end up with two elongated shapes which you can test against each other. If they overlap then you know that their paths cross and that there *may* be a collision.

[image]

Of course, knowing that there might be a collision is not hugely helpful. The problem is one AABB may be moving very slowly and the other very quickly so even though they both pass through the same space (their elongated shapes intersect) they don't pass through it at the same time.

Figuring out whether they both pass through the same space at the same time is hard, so instead we cheat. If you subtract the velocity of `B` from the velocity of `A` and then use this modified velocity to project the elongated shape of `A`, you can effectively treat `B` as a stationary object and still get the correct result. Knowing this, your test is now "does `B` overlap the elongated shape of `A`?". This is just a simple AABB vs Ngon problem.

While the above will give you a boolean as to whether two moving AABBs collide it will not tell you *when* they collide which is also useful for calculating things like rebounds.

I would very much recommend the book [Real Time Collision Detection by Christer Ericson](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Real-Time-Collision-Detection-Interactive-Technology/dp/1558607323) which is pretty much the go to book on collision detection for any aspiring game developer.

The following is a code snippet from the CD-ROM which accompanies the book. It tests a moving AABB against another moving AABB and also provides a time of first contact.

```
// Intersect AABBs ‘a’ and ‘b’ moving with constant velocities va and vb.
// On intersection, return time of first and last contact in tfirst and tlast
int IntersectMovingAABBAABB(AABB a, AABB b, Vector va, Vector vb, float &tfirst, float &tlast)
{
    // Exit early if ‘a’ and ‘b’ initially overlapping
    if (TestAABBAABB(a, b)) {
        tfirst = tlast = 0.0f;
        return 1;
    }

    // Use relative velocity; effectively treating ’a’ as stationary
    Vector v = vb - va;

    // Initialize times of first and last contact
    tfirst = 0.0f;
    tlast = 1.0f;

    // For each axis, determine times of first and last contact, if any
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (v[i] < 0.0f) {
            if (b.max[i] < a.min[i]) return 0;
            // Nonintersecting and moving apart
            if (a.max[i] < b.min[i]) tfirst = Max((a.max[i] - b.min[i]) / v[i], tfirst);
            if (b.max[i] > a.min[i]) tlast = Min((a.min[i] - b.max[i]) / v[i], tlast);
        }

        if (v[i] > 0.0f) {
            if (b.min[i] > a.max[i]) return 0;
            // Nonintersecting and moving apart
            if (b.max[i] < a.min[i]) tfirst = Max((a.min[i] - b.max[i]) / v[i], tfirst);
            if (a.max[i] > b.min[i]) tlast = Min((a.max[i] - b.min[i]) / v[i], tlast);
        }

        // No overlap possible if time of first contact occurs after time of last contact
        if (tfirst > tlast) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The following attribution is required by Elsevier's Software License Agreement:

> “from Real-Time Collision Detection by Christer Ericson, published by Morgan Kaufmann Publishers, © 2005 Elsevier Inc”